# How to "come out" from AFTER INSERT trigger when new data is inserted

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have tried to create trigger which does not allow completely ignore some table (TABLEB) and leave data empty in there. This works when nothing is inserted but how to come out from this trigger when something is added in TABLEB? I mean even if i insert or not it keeps saying "Data missing".

```
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON TABLEA
  FOR each ROW
DECLARE
    v_id number;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO   v_id
    FROM   id.TABLEB
    WHERE  id = v_id;
    IF v_id = 0 
    THEN raise_application_error(-20001, 
    'Data missing');
    END IF;
END;``

Oracle 19 in use. Help is appreciated. Thanks.
```

Comment: That looks like you are trying to reinvent referential integrity and enforce your own foreign key concept - if so, why; is this an assignment you've been given? (`WHERE  id = v_id` should be `WHERE  id = :new.id` I think, but...)

Comment: You declare `v_id` with a default value of `NULL` and then query the `TABLEB` table in the `id` schema and filter the rows to only include rows `WHERE id = v_id` which is the same as `WHERE id = NULL` which will never be true so `COUNT(*)` will always be zero and the exception will always be raised. What did you intend to happen?

Comment: How ho you initialize `v_id`? I'd say it is set to NULL when select count(*) is executed.